# Rails 3: How to display properly text from "textarea"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, textarea, newline

In my Rails 3 application I use `textarea` to let users to write a new message in a forum.

However, when the message is displayed, all newlines look like spaces (there is no `<br />`). Maybe there are other mismatch examples, I don't know yet.

I wonder what is the most appropriate way to deal with this.

I guess that the text that is stored in the database is OK (I see for example that `<` is converted to `&lt;`), so the main problem is the presentation.

Are there build-in helper methods in Rails for this ?

([simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) does something that looks similar to what I need, but it adds `<p>` tags which I don't want to appear.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Since `simple_format` does not do what you want**, I'd make a simple helper method to convert newlines to `<br>`s:

```
def nl2br(s)
  s.gsub(/\n/, '<br>')
end
```

Then in your view you can use it like this:

```
<%= nl2br(h(@forum_post.message)) %>
```

Comment: In Rails 3 the `h` method is by default and not needed.

Comment: Yeah, but in this case you need it because if you don't use it the br's will also be escaped. Like this, only the message is escaped and not the br's.

Comment: You should be using Rails' builtin `simple_format()` method, not rolling your own. Simple add this to your view: `<%=simple_format h @forum_post.message %>`

Comment: @Mischa, ah, they don't want the `<p>` tags wrapping the result. I still feel like that's a markup problem that they should be taking care of. In any regard, my bad.

Comment: Yes this is really helpful :)

Comment: Surprisingly the default behaviour of `simple_format` keeps the `\n` AND inserts a `<br/>`, causing formatting issues...  this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 78):

Rails got a helper method out of the box, so you dont have to write your own method.

From the documentation:

`simple_format(text, html_options={}, options={})`

```
my_text = "Here is some basic text...\n...with a line break."

simple_format(my_text)
# => "<p>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</p>"

more_text = "We want to put a paragraph...\n\n...right there."

simple_format(more_text)
# => "<p>We want to put a paragraph...</p>\n\n<p>...right there.</p>"

simple_format("Look ma! A class!", :class => 'description')
# => "<p class='description'>Look ma! A class!</p>"
```

Comment: Not exactly, this preserves HTML within the text.

Comment: This is Perfect answer for me.

Comment: The `(` `)` can be omitted e.g. `simple_format text` will work. A nice convenience if it's going in a lot of places

Answer (score 35):

You can use `style="white-space: pre-wrap;"` in the html tag surrounding the text. This respects any line breaks in the text.

Comment: This is by far the best answer, as it preserves the code logic. Code a problem with display? Then change the display, not the data !

Comment: I agree this is the best answer. Also, you might want to use white-space: pre-line, since pre-wrap indents line beginnings

Answer (score 8):

If someone still gets redirected here and uses Rails 4:
http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format

You can now specify the tag it gets wrapped in (defaults to p) like so:

```
simple_format(my_text, {}, wrapper_tag: "div")
# => "<div>Here is some basic text...\n<br />...with a line break.</div>"
```

Answer (score 8):

### CSS-only option

I believe one of the easiest options is to use css `white-space: pre-line;`

Other answers also mentioned using white-space, but I think it needs a little more information:

In most cases you should probably choose `pre-line` over `pre-wrap`. View the difference [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/).

It's very important to keep in mind about `white-space` that you should not do something like this:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;">
  <%= your.text %>
</p>
```

It will produce extra spaces and line-breaks in the output. Instead, go with this:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line;"><%= your.text %></p>
```

### HTML alternative

Another way is to wrap your text in `<pre>` tags. And last note on my CSS option is true here as well:

```
<p>
  <pre><%= your.text %></pre>
</p>
```

Don't separate your text from `<pre>` tags with spaces or line-breaks.

### Final thoughts

After googling this matter a little I have a feeling that html-approach is considered less clean than the css one and we should go css-way. However, html-way seems to be more browser-compatible (supports archaic browsers, but who cares):

[pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

[white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Answer (score 3):

The following helper preserves new lines as line breaks, and renders any HTML or Script (e.g Javscript) as plain text.

```
def with_new_lines(string)
   (h(string).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>')).html_safe
end
```

Use as so in views

```
<%= with_new_lines @object.some_text %>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just used `white-space: pre-line`. So next line (\n) will render it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert the plain text of the textarea to HTML.

At the most basic level you could run a string replacement:

```
 message_content.gsub! /\n/, '<br />'
```

You could also use a special format like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) (Ruby library: [BlueCloth](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth/)) or [Textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) (Ruby library: [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ace code-editor in my rails app and i had problem, that whenever i update or create the code, it adds always extra TAB on every line (except first). I couldn't solve it with gsub or javascript replace.. But it accidently solved itself when i disabled layout for that template.

So, i solved it with

```
render :layout => false
```