# How can I convert a newline to a <BR> tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the following text in a textarea:

```
Line 1 stuff.. Line 1 stuff.. Line 1 stuff.. Line 1 stuff.. Line 1 stuff.. 

Line 2 stuff.. Line 2 stuff.. Line 2 stuff.. Line 2 stuff.. Line 2 stuff..
```

I want to convert the new lines to `<BR>` tags, not use the simple_format `<P>` tags...

So I tried:

```
 str = str.gsub("\r\n", '<br>')
```

Problem is this is making two `<BR>` tags:

```
<div class="message">line 1<br><br>Line 2</div>
```

How can make just one `<BR>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3: How to display properly text from "textarea"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852377/rails-3-how-to-display-properly-text-from-textarea)

Comment: [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) used this way isn't [semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html); use something more appropriate, such as a paragraph or [list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Rails - is there a rails method to convert newlines to <br>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611609/), [Ruby on Rails: How can i convert/replace every newline to '<br/>'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405175/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = str.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, "<br>")
```

This will turn any number of consecutive `\r` and/or `\n` characters into a single `<br>`.

Answer (score 7):

Best way to do this is to use `simple_format(str)`:

> `simple_format()` is a helper function which will convert new lines
> and carriage returns to `<br>` and `<p>...</p>` tags.

reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Answer (score 1):

This would mean that you have two occurrences of "\r\n". So you could sanitize the input or expect this situation in your regex.

Have a look at this: [Ruby gsub / regex modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234741/ruby-gsub-regex-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

You have two line breaks in the input text. If you want there to be one `<br/>`, just do:

```
str = str.gsub("\r\n\r\n", '<br />');
```